# Please specify the product's option(s). Error - Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product

I've had this issue early, I've tried searching about this issue and I could not find anything helpful.

so what I'm trying to ask here, I've got this magento 1.9 server and the products are set up, with regards toe adding to cart for simple products, it works smoothly and fine, but when I try to add configurable product this message returns.

> Please specify the product's option(s).

Now I was tracing the code and working on it, till i reached here.

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController

in this file this code for adding the product exists:

```
/**
 * Add product to shopping cart action
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function addAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_goBack();
        return;
    }
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);


        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');


        /**
         * Check product availability
         */
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
        echo 'here';
        ?>
            <pre>
                <?php print_r($params); ?>
            </pre>
        <?php
            exit;
        ?>
        <?php

        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        /**
         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

in this code I used this simple code to achive where i'm and what data i have.

```
echo 'here';
?>
    <pre>
        <?php print_r($params); ?>
    </pre>
<?php
    exit;
?>
<?php
```

This simple code return the arguments i have for my Configurable Product.

```
Array
(
    [uenc] => aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcudmF0dHJlbmEuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9nZW5lcmFsLWplYW5zMTMuaHRtbA,,
    [product] => 65
    [form_key] => qIGyp6YDp7kQjibA
    [related_product] => 
    [super_attribute] => Array
        (
            [168] => M
        )

    [qty] => 1
)
```

That mean all attributes is chosen, but after this simple code when i reach the

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

it suppose to go to this file

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php

On this function

```
/**
 * Add product to shopping cart (quote)
 *
 * @param   int|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $productInfo
 * @param   mixed $requestInfo
 * @return  Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
 */
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
{
    $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
    $request = $this->_getProductRequest($requestInfo);

    $productId = $product->getId();

    if ($product->getStockItem()) {
        $minimumQty = $product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
        //If product was not found in cart and there is set minimal qty for it
        if ($minimumQty && $minimumQty > 0 && $request->getQty() < $minimumQty
            && !$this->getQuote()->hasProductId($productId)
        ){
            $request->setQty($minimumQty);
        }
    }

    if ($productId) {
        try {
            $result = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->setUseNotice(false);
            $result = $e->getMessage();
        }
        /**
         * String we can get if prepare process has error
         */
        if (is_string($result)) {
            $redirectUrl = ($product->hasOptionsValidationFail())
                ? $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl(
                    $product,
                    array('_query' => array('startcustomization' => 1))
                )
                : $product->getProductUrl();
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);
            if ($this->getCheckoutSession()->getUseNotice() === null) {
                $this->getCheckoutSession()->setUseNotice(true);
            }
            Mage::throwException($result);
        }
    } else {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The product does not exist.'));
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
    $this->getCheckoutSession()->setLastAddedProductId($productId);
    return $this;
}
```

But when i try to `echo` anything in this function, it won't appear and redirected to the configurable product page with This message

> Please specify the product's option(s).
>   Thank you in advanced to anyone who can help me with this issue, especially for trying to help

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this? Adding products via URL? Or add to cart buttons that show up on pages that are NOT the product pages (ex: categories, widgets )

Comment: it's the controller which has the add to cart function, i'm trying to add product by add to cart button on product page or in quick view popup page

Comment: So adding to the cart does not work at all for configurable products on any page? Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: yeah i'm using custom theme called meigee. "black & white"

Comment: I'd say: Step 1, revert back to the default Magento theme and test it out. If it works, we can be more certain the problem is with "black & white" theme. If it is your custom theme causing the problem, we can look into what is causing the error. Are there any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: i did that, and i found the problem was in the attributes options, it doesn't send the proper value, that's what was the problem i fix it, thanks a lot for your time bro :-)